# Is the following phrase appropriate for my notifications screen?

Tags: gui-design, notification, mobile-application

I'm working on a mobile app which allows users to book and share taxi journeys. One of the features in the app is a notifications screen which alerts the user each time they get a request for a seat in one of their journeys. I wanted to ask is the following phrase appropriate:

"**Username** wants to share."

Tapping on the notification gives more information. What do you think of this - is it a good phrase to use or can I improve it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems off to me to use the word "share" like that; it would feel better if you used it as a transitive verb. It would be better if you could make it less generic as well, something that would be more specific to just taxis/etc.:

- Paul wants to share a cab.
- Paul wants to ride with you.
- Paul would like a seat.

Comment: +1 for "share a cab" - The mockup doesn't show me any context.  It made me think of sharing photos or status updates without the word "cab" in there.

Answer (score 1):

1) You're sharing a ride from A to B, not a person. The difference is subtle, but in effect it's going to be more interesting to give a prominent place to the start and finish of this trip. That way you'll get an idea of what is actually being offered. Then make "Paul" secondary.

2) *Paul wants to share* is great, but I don't care that that person wants to do something. It's about what **I** want. So perhaps turn it into **Paul is offering**. That way it sounds like an offer, rather than sounding like a notification about someone who wants to do something.

Otherwise, and this could help in the marketing aspect, perhaps call your service "hitch" or something other noun and say "Paul shared a hitch".